# Changing a number in a txt.file with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

[Text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrNJe.png)
I am new here and I want t know how to change the value of a number in a text file.

This is for a project I am working on for the company I work for.

The number is used to create new project numbers by clicking a single button.

With the code in the file below I can read the text from the file on my desktop and put it in a cell in Excel. But after that I want the number to increase by 10.

Can somebody please help me.

Thanks alot in advance.

```
Sub Hallo()

Dim X As Double
Dim TXT As String


Open "C:\Users\Leon\Desktop\Project nummer.txt" For Input As #1

    Do While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, TXT
    Sheets("Blad1").Range("C2") = TXT
    Loop
    
Close #1

End Sub
```

Comment: "the number to increase by 10." Do you mean the number in the file or the one on the sheet ? What is X ?

Comment: I want to change the number in the text file on my desktop by 10, X means nothing, I removed it from the code after I posted this question 
@CDP1802

Comment: In that case you need to show example of text file. Your code reads the number from the last line, is that the line you want to change ?

Comment: Yes it is, the text file is litteraly just the numer, nothing else.

Comment: @CDP1802, I added a picture with the text file. That number I want to increase by 10 every time I run the Macro, It also  needs to save the text file afterwards, so I cant create the same project numbers twice.

Answer (score 0):

Write back to the file

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Hallo()

    Const FOLDER = "C:\Users\Leon\Desktop\"
    Const FILENAME = "Project nummer.txt"
    Const INC = 10
    
    Dim s As String, ff
    
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FOLDER & FILENAME For Input As #ff
    Line Input #ff, s
    Close #ff
    
    If IsNumeric(s) Then
    
        Sheets("Blad1").Range("C2") = Format(s, 0)
        
        ' save new number
        ff = FreeFile()
        Open FOLDER & FILENAME For Output As #ff
        Write #ff, Val(s) + INC
        Close #ff
    
    Else
        MsgBox s & " not valid number", vbCritical
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This works exactly how I wanted it to work. 
You are amazing, thank you so much!!

Comment: You just need to be aware that, in theory, two persons can access the file with the old value ("race condition") and use the same project number

Comment: Luckily we don't make new projects every day :P. Mostly our boss does those things, but thanks for the tip anyway.